# Dynamic number of lines on chart

Tags: javascript, c#, linq, d3.js

I currently have a d3 multiseries line chart which displays how many emails and phone calls have been received.

My data retrieval and data structure is as follows:

```
var allCommunications = _uow.CommunicationRepository.Get()
                                .Where(c => c.DateOpened.Year == year)
                                .GroupBy(c => new { c.Method, c.DateOpened.Month })
                                .Select(g => new
                                 {
                                     Type = g.Key.Method,
                                     xVal = g.Key.Month,
                                     Value = g.Count()
                                 });
```

This is then converted to the following structure:

```
public class LineChartData
{
    public int xValue { get; set; }
    public int EmailValue { get; set; }
    public int PhoneValue { get; set; }
}
```

The graph is created using the following javascript:

```
function buildCommunicationLineChart(data, placeholder, callback, type) {
var margin = { top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 40, left: 50 },
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    emailLineColour = "#779ECB", phoneLineColour = "#FF6961", tooltipTextColour = "white";

var x;

if (type == "month") {
    var x = d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain([1, 31])
                    .range([0, width]);
} else if (type == "year")
{
    var x = d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain([1, 12])
                    .range([0, width]);
}


var minPhone = Math.min.apply(Math, data.map(function (o) { return o.PhoneValue }));
var maxPhone = Math.max.apply(Math, data.map(function (o) { return o.PhoneValue }));
var minEmail = Math.min.apply(Math, data.map(function (o) { return o.EmailValue }));
var maxEmail = Math.max.apply(Math, data.map(function (o) { return o.EmailValue }));

var minY = Math.min(minPhone, minEmail);
var maxY = Math.max(maxPhone, maxEmail);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([minY, maxY + 5])
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .tickSize(-height)
    .tickPadding(10)
    .tickSubdivide(true)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .tickPadding(10)
    .tickSize(-width)
    .tickSubdivide(true)
    .orient("left");

if (type == "month") {
    var emailTip = d3.tip()
      .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
      .offset([-10, 0])
      .html(function (d) {
          return "<strong>Emails:</strong> <span style='color:"+tooltipTextColour+"'>" + d.EmailValue + "</span><br /><strong>Day of Month:</strong><span style='color:white'>" + d.xValue + "</span>";
      });

    var phoneTip = d3.tip()
      .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
      .offset([-10, 0])
      .html(function (d) {
          return "<strong>Calls:</strong> <span style='color:" + tooltipTextColour + "'>" + d.PhoneValue + "</span><br /><strong>Day of Month:</strong><span style='color:white'>" + d.xValue + "</span>";
      });
}
else if (type == "year") {
    var emailTip = d3.tip()
      .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
      .offset([-10, 0])
      .html(function (d) {
          return "<strong>Emails:</strong> <span style='color:" + tooltipTextColour + "'>" + d.EmailValue + "</span><br /><strong>Month of Year:</strong><span style='color:white'>" + d.xValue + "</span>";
      });

    var phoneTip = d3.tip()
      .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
      .offset([-10, 0])
      .html(function (d) {
          return "<strong>Calls:</strong> <span style='color:" + tooltipTextColour + "'>" + d.PhoneValue + "</span><br /><strong>Month of Year:</strong><span style='color:white'>" + d.xValue + "</span>";
      });
}

var svg = placeholder.append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right + 50)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .attr("class", "chart")
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

svg.call(emailTip);
svg.call(phoneTip);

if (type == "year") {
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .append("text")
        .attr("class", "axis-label")
        .attr("transform", "none")
        .attr("y", (-margin.left) + 530)
        .attr("x", -height + 860)
        .text('Month');
}
else if (type == "month") {
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .append("text")
        .attr("class", "axis-label")
        .attr("transform", "none")
        .attr("y", (-margin.left) + 525)
        .attr("x", -height + 860)
        .text('Day');
}        

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "axis-label")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", (-margin.left) + 15)
    .attr("x", -height / 2)
    .text('Communications');

svg.append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var emailLine = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("linear")
    .x(function (d) { return x(d.xValue); })
    .y(function (d) { return y(d.EmailValue); });

var phoneLine = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("linear")
    .x(function (d) { return x(d.xValue); })
    .y(function (d) { return y(d.PhoneValue); });

svg.selectAll('.emailLine')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr('stroke', emailLineColour)
        .attr("d", emailLine(data));

svg.selectAll("circle.emailLine")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("svg:circle")
        .attr("class", "emailLine")
        .style("fill", emailLineColour)
        .attr("cx", emailLine.x())
        .attr("cy", emailLine.y())
        .attr("r", 5)
        .on('mouseover', emailTip.show)
        .on('mouseout', emailTip.hide);

svg.selectAll('.phoneLine')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr('stroke', phoneLineColour)
    .attr("d", phoneLine(data));

svg.selectAll("circle.phoneLine")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("svg:circle")
        .attr("class", "phoneLine")
        .style("fill", phoneLineColour)
        .attr("cx", phoneLine.x())
        .attr("cy", phoneLine.y())
        .attr("r", 5)
        .on('mouseover', phoneTip.show)
        .on('mouseout', phoneTip.hide);

svg.append("text")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (x(data[data.length - 1].xValue) + 5) + "," + y(data[data.length - 1].EmailValue) + ")")
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .style("fill", emailLineColour)
    .text("Email");

svg.append("text")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (x(data[data.length - 1].xValue) + 5) + "," + y(data[data.length - 1].PhoneValue) + ")")
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .style("fill", phoneLineColour)
    .text("Phone");

if (callback) {
    callback();
}
}
```

Obviously this is very long and very limited due to each series for the chart being hardcoded. Therefore, it would be quite a bit of work if another method of communication is added. My idea behind resolving this is to have a dynamic number of series and create a line for each series. Therefore i guess my data structure would have to be something like:

```
public class LineChartData
{
    public string Type {get;set;} //for the label
    public Data Data{get;set;}
}

public class Data
{
    public int xValue { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Or something similar?

So i guess my question is, would this be the correct approach to structuring my data, any suggestions to change my query to do this, and how would i edit my javascript in order to account for this.

Apologies for the long winded question and thanks in advance for any help.

If any more info is required, please ask and i will provide anything i can.

Thanks,

**EDIT:**

Here is my updated code after attempting the suggestion by Mark below:

```
function buildCommunicationLineChart(data, placeholder, callback, type) {
var margin = { top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 40, left: 50 },
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    emailLineColour = "#779ECB", phoneLineColour = "#FF6961", tooltipTextColour = "white";

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var nest = d3.nest()
              .key(function (d) { return d.Type; })
              .entries(data);

var x;

if (type == "month") {
    var x = d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain([1, 31])
                    .range([0, width]);
} else if (type == "year")
{
    var x = d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain([1, 12])
                    .range([0, width]);
}

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 100])
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .tickSize(-height)
    .tickPadding(10)
    .tickSubdivide(true)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .tickPadding(10)
    .tickSize(-width)
    .tickSubdivide(true)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
            .interpolate("linear")
            .x(function (d) { return x(d.xValue); })
            .y(function (d) { return y(d.Value); });

var svg = placeholder.append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right + 50)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .attr("class", "chart")
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

if (type == "year") {
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .append("text")
        .attr("class", "axis-label")
        .attr("transform", "none")
        .attr("y", (-margin.left) + 530)
        .attr("x", -height + 860)
        .text('Month');
}
else if (type == "month") {
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .append("text")
        .attr("class", "axis-label")
        .attr("transform", "none")
        .attr("y", (-margin.left) + 525)
        .attr("x", -height + 860)
        .text('Day');
}        

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "axis-label")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", (-margin.left) + 15)
    .attr("x", -height / 2)
    .text('Communications');

svg.append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "clip")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

color.domain(d3.keys(nest[0]).filter(function (key) { return key === nest[0].key; }));

var methods = color.domain().map(function (commType) {
    return {
        commType: commType,
        values: nest.map(function (d) {
            return { xValue: d.xVal, Value: d.Value };
        })
    };
});

x.domain(d3.extent(nest, function (d) { return d.xVal; }));

y.domain([
    d3.min(methods, function (m) { return d3.min(m.values, function (v) { return v.Value; }); }),
    d3.max(methods, function (m) { return d3.max(m.values, function (v) { return v.Value; }); })
]);

var method = svg.selectAll('.method')
                    .data(methods)
                    .enter().append('g')
                    .attr('class', 'method');

method.append('path')
        .attr('class', 'line')
        .attr('d', function (d) { return line(d.values); })
        .attr('stroke', function (d) { return color(d.commType); });

method.append('text')
        .datum(function (d) { return { commType: d.commType, value: d.values[d.values.length - 1] }; })
        .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + x(d.value.xVal) + "," + y(d.value.Value) + ")"; })
        .attr('x', 3)
        .attr('dy', '.35em')
        .text(function (d) { return d.commType; });

if (callback) {
    callback();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question might be a little too broad for StackOverflow, but I'll try to help. The way I always approach the question of how should my API output data, is to ask how is my data going to be consumed on the front-end?  In this case, you are trying to create a `d3` multi-line chart and `d3` will want an array of objects containing an array of data points (here's a great [example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955)).  Something like this in JSON:

```
[
  {
    key: 'Email', //<-- identifies the line
    values: [ //<-- points for the line
      {
        xVal: '20160101',
        Value: 10
      }, {
        xVal: '20160102',
        Value: 20
      }, ...
    ]
  }, {
    key: 'Phone',
    values: [
      {
        xVal: 'Jan',
        Value: 30
      }, {
        xVal: '20160102',
        Value: 25
      }, ...
    ]
  },
  ...
]
```

Now the question becomes how to get your data into a structure like that.  Given many hours, you could probably write a linq statement that'll do **but**, I kinda like returning a flat JSON object (after all if we are writing a re-useable restful interface, flat is the most useful).  So, how then would we make that final jump for our *easy to use d3 structure*.  Given your:

```
.Select(g => new
{
   Type = g.Key.Method,
   xVal = g.Key.Month,
   Value = g.Count()
});
```

would produce a JSON object like:

```
[{"Type":"Phone","xVal":"Feb","Value":1},{"Type":"Email","xVal":"Jan","Value":3},{"Type":"Phone","xVal":"Jan","Value":1}]
```

`d3` could then get to our "easy to work with" format as easy as:

```
var nest = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.Type; })
  .entries(data);
```

Which produces:

```
[  
   {  
      "key":"Phone",
      "values":[  
         {  
            "Type":"Phone",
            "xVal":"Feb",
            "Value":1
         },
         {  
            "Type":"Phone",
            "xVal":"Jan",
            "Value":1
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "key":"Email",
      "values":[  
         {  
            "Type":"Email",
            "xVal":"Jan",
            "Value":3
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

From this structure, your multi-line chart becomes a breeze....

---

**EDITS FOR COMMENTS**

I really didn't understand what you were attempting to do with some of your code (in particular with your `methods` variable - the data was already in a great format for `d3`).  So I refactored a bit:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>

  <style>
    body {
      font: 10px sans-serif;
    }
    
    .axis path,
    .axis line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }
    
    .x.axis path {
      display: none;
    }
    
    .line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    // function buildCommunicationLineChart(data, placeholder, callback, type) {
    var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 30,
        bottom: 40,
        left: 50
      },
      width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var colors = {
      "Phone": "#FF6961",
      "Email": "#779ECB"
    }
    
    var color = d3.scale.category10();

    var data = [{
      "Type": "Phone",
      "xValue": 1,
      "Value": 5
    }, {
      "Type": "Email",
      "xValue": 1,
      "Value": 7
    }, {
      "Type": "Email",
      "xValue": 2,
      "Value": 1
    }, {
      "Type": "Phone",
      "xValue": 2,
      "Value": 4
    }, {
      "Type": "Phone",
      "xValue": 4,
      "Value": 2
    }];

    var nest = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d) {
        return d.Type;
      })
      .entries(data);

    var x;
    var type = "month";
    if (type == "month") {
      var x = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([1, 31])
        .range([0, width]);
    } else if (type == "year") {
      var x = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([1, 12])
        .range([0, width]);
    }

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, 100])
      .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .tickSize(-height)
      .tickPadding(10)
      .tickSubdivide(true)
      .orient("bottom");

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .tickPadding(10)
      .tickSize(-width)
      .tickSubdivide(true)
      .orient("left");

    var line = d3.svg.line()
      .interpolate("linear")
      .x(function(d) {
        return x(d.xValue);
      })
      .y(function(d) {
        return y(d.Value);
      });

    var svg = d3.select('body').append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right + 50)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .attr("class", "chart")
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
      
    y.domain([
      0,
      d3.max(nest, function(t) { return d3.max(t.values, function(v) { return v.Value; }); })
    ]);
    
    x.domain([
      d3.min(nest, function(t) { return d3.min(t.values, function(v) { return v.xValue; }); }),
      d3.max(nest, function(t) { return d3.max(t.values, function(v) { return v.xValue; }); })
    ]);
    
    nest.forEach(function(d){
      for (var i = x.domain()[0]; i <= x.domain()[1]; i++){
        if (!d.values.some(function(v){ return (v.xValue === i) })){
          d.values.splice((i - 1), 0, {xValue: i, Value: 0});
        }
      }
    });
    
    var xAxis = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

    if (type == "year") {
      xAxis
        .append("text")
        .attr("class", "axis-label")
        .attr("transform", "none")
        .attr("y", margin.top + 15)
        .attr("x", width / 2)
        .text('Month');
    } else if (type == "month") {
      xAxis
        .append("text")
        .attr("class", "axis-label")
        .attr("y", margin.top + 15)
        .attr("x", width / 2)
        .text('Day')
        .style('text-anchor', 'middle');
    }

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
      .append("text")
      .attr("class", "axis-label")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", (-margin.left) + 15)
      .attr("x", -height / 2)
      .text('Communications')
      .style('text-anchor', 'middle');

    svg.append("clipPath")
      .attr("id", "clip")
      .append("rect")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height);

    /*
    color.domain(d3.keys(nest[0]).filter(function(key) {
      return key === nest[0].key;
    }));

    var methods = color.domain().map(function(commType) {
      return {
        commType: commType,
        values: nest.map(function(d) {
          return {
            xValue: d.xVal,
            Value: d.Value
          };
        })
      };
    });
    */

    var method = svg.selectAll('.method')
      .data(nest)
      .enter().append('g')
      .attr('class', 'method');

    method.append('path')
      .attr('class', 'line')
      .attr('d', function(d) {
        return line(d.values);
      })
      .style('stroke', function(d) {
        return color(d.key);
        // OR if you want to use you defined ones
        //return colors[d.key];
      });

    method.append('text')
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        var len = d.values.length - 1;
        return "translate(" + x(d.values[len].xValue) + "," + y(d.values[len].Value) + ")";
      })
      .attr('x', 3)
      .attr('dy', '.35em')
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.key;
      });

    //if (callback) {
    //  callback();
    //}
    //  }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

**EDIT FOR COMMENTS 2**

That's actually a tricky question.  How about:

```
// for each dataset
nest.forEach(function(d){
  // loop our domain
  for (var i = x.domain()[0]; i <= x.domain()[1]; i++){
    // if there's no xValue at that location
    if (!d.values.some(function(v){ return (v.xValue === i) })){
      // add a zero in place
      d.values.splice((i - 1), 0, {xValue: i, Value: 0});
    }
  }
});
```

Code sample above is edited also.

Comment: Thank you for this. I will try this when i get to work tomorrow. I like the approach of d3.nest(). Is there any advantage to using this approach rather than manipulating it in c# and passing through the formatted data? Thanks

Comment: I have attempted your suggestion along with trying to follow this post https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955 but i cannot seem to get it to work. i believe it may be the color.domain screwing things up but i am unsure how to implement it without this as that is how the example does it. I have put my updated code in the question edit if you would be able to take a look thatd be great. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Thats great thank you. Everything seems to be working now. My last thing i need to do for this is have d3 treat a missing value as 0 so that i solid line appears on the graph. Currently, it only shows a dot if there is only one value. The x data is month of year or day of year so is it possible to iterate over x data points and insert 0 if there isnt a value present?

Comment: that looks brilliant. Ill give it a go first thing in the morning. Is there an advantage between doing it like u suggest / through javascript using the underscore library / through c# before returning the data? Many thanks for your help. Even if i cant get this working (dont see why i wouldnt be able to) i am accepting this as the answer

Comment: I have also asked the question here so that you could post the answer there for others to be able to find it http://stackoverflow.com/q/35630197/2858948