# D3 chart missing data

Tags: javascript, c#, d3.js

I have a d3 line graph which works perfectly. It maps the number of telephone calls and emails received in the current month or current year. However, the only issue is that if phone calls were only received on one day of the month, then only a dot appears at that value. What i would like to happen is that for every day there is not a value then the value is treated as 0. I have had a look around google but i can only find examples of going the other way. Is anybody able to help?

My code as it stands is:

```
function buildCommunicationLineChart(data, placeholder, callback, type) {
var margin = { top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 40, left: 50 },
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    tooltipTextColour = "white";

var color = ["#FF9797", "#86BCFF", "#33FDC0", "#EFA9FE", "#7BCAE1", "#8C8CFF", "#80B584", "#C88E8E", "#DD597D", "#D8F0F8", "#DD597D", "#D6C485", "#990099", "#5B5BFF", "#1FCB4A", "#000000", "#00BFFF", "#BE81F7", "#BDBDBD", "#F79F81"];

if (type == "month") {
    var x = d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain([1, 31])
                    .range([0, width]);

    var tip = d3.tip()
      .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
      .offset([-10, 0])
      .html(function (d) {
          return "<strong>Value:</strong> <span style='color:" + tooltipTextColour + "'>" + d.Value + "</span><br /><strong>Day of Month:</strong><span style='color:white'>" + d.xValue + "</span>";
      });
}
else if (type == "year")
{
    var x = d3.scale.linear()
                    .domain([1, 12])
                    .range([0, width]);

    var tip = d3.tip()
      .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
      .offset([-10, 0])
      .html(function (d) {
          return "<strong>Value:</strong> <span style='color:" + tooltipTextColour + "'>" + d.Value + "</span><br /><strong>Month of Year:</strong><span style='color:white'>" + d.xValue + "</span>";
      });
}

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 60])
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .tickSize(-height)
    .tickPadding(10)
    .tickSubdivide(true)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .tickPadding(10)
    .tickSize(-width)
    .tickSubdivide(true)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function (d) { var xTest = x(d.xValue); return x(d.xValue); })
            .y(function (d) { var yTest = y(d.Value); return y(d.Value); });

var svg = placeholder.append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right + 50)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .attr("class", "chart")
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

if (type == "year") {
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .append("text")
        .attr("class", "axis-label")
        .attr("transform", "none")
        .attr("y", (-margin.left) + 530)
        .attr("x", -height + 860)
        .text('Month');
}
else if (type == "month") {
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .append("text")
        .attr("class", "axis-label")
        .attr("transform", "none")
        .attr("y", (-margin.left) + 525)
        .attr("x", -height + 860)
        .text('Day');
}

var methods = d3.entries(data);
y.domain([
    d3.min(methods, function (c) { return d3.min(c.value.DataPoints, function (v) { return v.Value; }); }) -1,
    d3.max(methods, function (c) { return d3.max(c.value.DataPoints, function (v) { return v.Value; }); }) +1
]);

svg.call(tip);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "axis-label")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", (-margin.left) + 15)
    .attr("x", -height / 2)
    .text('Communications');

var method = svg.selectAll('.method')
                    .data(methods)
                    .enter().append('g')
                    .attr('class', 'method')
                    .style('fill',function(d,i){
                        return color[i];
                    })
                    .style('stroke', function (d, i) {
                        return color[i];
                    });

var m = method.append('path')
        .attr('class', function (d, i) { return 'line line-' + i; })
        .attr('d', function (d) { return line(d.value.DataPoints); });

method.selectAll('circle')
        .data(function (d) { return d.value.DataPoints; })
         .enter().append("circle")
        .attr('class', function (d, i) { return 'circle circle-' + i; })
         .attr("cx", function (dd) { return x(dd.xValue); })
         .attr("cy", function (dd) { return y(dd.Value); })
         .attr("r", 3.5)
         .on('mouseover', tip.show)
         .on('mouseout', tip.hide);

method.append('text')
        .datum(function (d) { return { commType: d.value.Type, value: d.value.DataPoints[d.value.DataPoints.length - 1] }; })
        .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + x(d.value.xValue) + "," + y(d.value.Value) + ")"; })
        .attr('x', 5)
        .attr('class',function(d,i){return 'text text-'+i;})
        .attr('dy', '.15em')
        .style('stroke','none')
        .text(function (d) { return d.commType; });

if (callback) {
    callback();
}
}
```

Many Thanks :)

**EDIT**

xVal is the day number of month number:

```
[{
    "Type": "Email",
    "DataPoints": [{
        "xValue": 1,
        "Value": 17
    },
    {
        "xValue": 2,
        "Value": 59
    }]
},
{
    "Type": "Phone",
    "DataPoints": [{
        "xValue": 1,
        "Value": 1
    }]
}]
```

Comment: Can you post data sample which cause this issue? If it s just because you dont have value on your dataset where there is no call, just pre process your data adding missing day with zero value. I need your data struct to be more precise.

Comment: @JulienLeray I have edited my question to provide my data structure and retrieval in c#. I hope this helps. Let me know if i can provide anything else :)

Comment: Actually I was speaking of Json data sample. Like a Json month calls/mail number you want to display which have only one day.

Comment: Apologies i do not have much experience of json to create it from my object and do not know how to view it in visual studio. Any advice how i can obtain the json of my data?

Comment: @JulienLeray I have now added some example json data. As you can see, emails will be a short line of 2 points and phone will be a single point. How can i make all months of the year for missing values result in 0 and plotted

Comment: You have to solutions. Make your API or whatever send you data pre filling days of each month where arent present. Or do it directly client side after you received your data in Js. The only teick you will have to do is find the number of day for each month. I will be more precise on answer soon, i m in the teain right now

Comment: Yes if you could provide an example that would be brilliant. I am happy to assume that all months have 31 days, Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With JSON structured like:

```
[{
    "Type": "Email",
    "DataPoints": [{
        "xValue": 1,
        "Value": 17
    },
    {
        "xValue": 2,
        "Value": 59
    }]
},
{
    "Type": "Phone",
    "DataPoints": [{
        "xValue": 1,
        "Value": 1
    }]
}]
```

And assuming your `DataPoints` array is sorted by `xValue` and 31 days in the month:

```
var maxDaysInMonth = 31;
// for each dataset
dataset.forEach(function(d){
  // loop our month
  for (var i = 1; i <= maxDaysInMonth; i++){
    // if there's no xValue at that location
    if (!d.DataPoints.some(function(v){ return (v.xValue === i) })){
      // add a zero in place
      d.values.splice((i - 1), 0, {xValue: i, Value: 0});
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: could you tell me whether this method is better performance wise than Julien's answer below? Thanks

Comment: @DaRoGa, it's essentially the same code.  Unless you have tens of thousands of points, I can't see it mattering.

Comment: I have accepted this answer as i do not want to add additional libraries (underscore.js) to my project for a small method. However i will look into this library to see its uses elsewhere. Thanks both for your help

Answer (score 2):

I will assume some points:

You are receiving from your data source year's array of month's arrays (if you are receiving month by month you will have to make a Get request for each month, it's pretty easy, but I hope you have a route giving you data on year, would not be cool to do 12 http get for this result) data like:

```
[
    {
        month: "January",
        data: [{
        "Type": "Email",
        "DataPoints": 
            [{
                "xValue": 1,
                "Value": 17
            },
            {
                "xValue": 2,
                "Value": 59
            }]
        },
        {
            "Type": "Phone",
            "DataPoints": [{
                "xValue": 1,
                "Value": 1
            }]
        }]
    }
    },{
    month: "February",
    data: [...]
    },
    ...
]
```

I will do that client side in Js:

Assuming each month is 31 days, i'm too lazy to think about doing it exactly but it shoudn't be that difficult, and xValue is the day of the month.

```
function completeMonths(data){
    _.each(data, function(month){
        _.each(month.data, function(typeSource){
            for(var i = 1; i < 32; i++){
                var dayOnList = _.some(typeSource.DataPoints, function(day){
                    return day.xValue == i;
                });
                if(!dayOnList)
                    typeSource.DataPoints.push({xValue: i, Value: 0});
            }
            typeSource.DataPoints = _.sortBy(typeSource.DataPoints, function(ite){
                return ite.xValue;
            });
        });
    });

    return data;
}
```

Probably not the more optimized code, but I've tried it and it's working.
Actually I think it would be better to map the month's days present, and reject them from and 1 to 31 array.
Btw your Json isn't well formatted, you're missing a closing "]".

Comment: using this i get _ is undefined?

Comment: No i have never heard of these

Comment: okay... it's would be way more verbose on vanilla js. You should consider one of those there really good and useful tools for this kind of treatment

Comment: I have implemented this as you suggested, however, d3 plots the original points and then plots the new points so it scews the graph horribly. Is there perhaps a way using underscore.js that you know of where i can sort the data by type and then xval as i think this may sort the issue. Thanks,

Comment: i have attempted _.sortBy(data,function{return d.DataPoints.xValue}) as well as _.sortBy(data,function{return d.Type, d.DataPoints.xValue}) but neither seemed to do the trick

Comment: give me a sample of your json data format output you want, I don't get what you want.

Comment: The json to go into the graph is as it is laid out in Mark's answer. However, i need the DataPoints for each Type ordered by xValue so that they are plotted on the graph in the correct order

Comment: Ho, so you just want each DataPoints array ordered by xValues?

Comment: Yes so each type contains an ordered list of data points. i dont care about the order of the types too much